# Random generate element in numpy with probability

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate an array in numpy (there are N numbers).

There are only two kinds of element in this array, for example: 3.0 and -3.0. The probability of occurring 3.0 is 0.4, and the probability of occurring -3.0 is 0.6.

How to generate such an array?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Comment: `np.random.choice([0.3, -0.3], p=[0.4, 0.6])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
n=10
np.random.choice([3,-3],n,p=[0.4,0.6])
```